# Django middleware process_template_response setup

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-middleware

I would like to create a function that checks if the user has any notifications. If they do, the number should be displayed in the navbar.

Could someone please help me refactor this to do just that?

Thank you!

***middleware.py:***

```
def process_template_response(self, request, response):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        try:
            notifications = Notification.objects.all_for_user(request.user).unread()
            count = notifications.count()
            context = {
                "count": count
            }
            response = TemplateResponse(request, 'navbar.html', context)
            return response
        except:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

***navbar.html:***

```
<li >
    <a href="{% url 'notifications_all' %}">
        {% if count > 0 %}Notifications ({{ count }}){% else %}Notifications{% endif %}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why would you do that in middleware? That's a job for a template tag.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Would you be able to explain how to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have work in something like this before, I think you should use the `context_data` response's attribute:

```
class NotificationMiddleware(object):
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                notifications = Notification.objects.all_for_user(request.user).unread()
                count = notifications.count()
                response.context_data['count'] = count  # I recomend you to use other name instead of 'count'
                return response
            except Exception, e:
                print e  # Fix possible errors
                return response
        else:
            return response
```

Then you need register this class in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` tuple in your `settings` file:

```
# settings.py
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Django middlewares
    ....
    'yourapp.middleware.NotificationMiddleware',
)
```

The example above assumes you have a `middleware` folder inside your application named 'yourapp'.

Finally you should be able to use `{{ count }}` in template.

Comment: Thank you! How would I show which template this is for?

Comment: This will process all requests, so you can use `{{ count }}` in every template.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me. It doesn't seem as if anything is coming through

Comment: Have you register it in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings file?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I made a mistake it is `context_data` instead of `context`

Comment: Can you trace it, insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and be sure the query and everything is right, be sure no error is triggered, test every line.

Comment: Remember you are inside a `try - except` block, so if an error is happening that will just `pass`.